# Фотографий в ленте как у ВК, есть ли готовые решения?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, изображения, gallery

Есть блок, например квадратный.

Есть не-определённое количество картинок.

---

Нужно расположить картинки так, чтобы они занимали всё пространство.

Точно такой-же функционал есть у ВК (картинки ниже).

Есть готовые решения для этой задачи? Или нужно писать с нуля?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Готового решения по-моему нет, самое простое, что я вижу это с помощью js считать серднее количество картинок в ряд, округлять до целого и назначать им размер, так же есть гриды

Comment: нашёл для реакта https://github.com/Expertizo/react-fb-image-grid
но нужно для Vue, ещё буду искать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для Vue посмотрите vue-masonry-css:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-masonry-css
https://paulcollett.github.io/vue-masonry-css/demo/

Comment: про mansory конечно же знаем, но тут немного другая задача